# executeScript in background page fails silently only when DevTools undocked

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

My DevTools extension injects script into the inspected window in order to parse and receive messages from-- normally on page load, but also when DevTools is first opened.

The relevant line in the background page is as follows:

```
chrome.tabs.executeScript(message.tabId,{ file: 'insert.js', runAt: 'document_idle' },function(results){console.log(results);});
```

This line normally displays `[null]` in the background console upon success-- and is successful both when opening DevTools in docked state, and when a user navigates to a new URL with DevTools in any state. It's only not working when DevTools is opened in an undocked state; in that case, the call is failing silently and `results` is returning `undefined`.

Permissions are "tabs", "http://*/*", "https://*/*"; and again, it's only not working in this one very specific case.

Is this a known issue with a workaround or should I consider this a Chromium bug?

Comment: You totally should file that as a bug, as Chromium team is not very quick to react. You can always leave a comment to close the bug if you figure out it's not a bug

Comment: Can you post the context of that call? Which events fire it?

Comment: @Xan it's running in an anonymous function set as the reaction to a runtime.onMessage listener in the event page. `console` calls in the same function on either side of `executeScript` fire normally. `insert.js` is a small code block to inject a script tag into the tab, so maybe it's **that** that's failing--  
`var insertScript = 'lots of raw escaped JS'; blah = document.createElement('script'); blah.innerHTML = insertScript; blah.type = 'text/javascript'; document.head.appendChild(blah);`

Comment: Is `message.tabId` actually a valid tabId (integer)? I guess not.

Comment: @RobW tabId is valid in all of these cases regardless of failing or not failing.

Comment: Then I suggest to create a self-contained test case and report it at http://crbug.com/new. I will make sure that it gets to the right people.

Comment: @RobW Thank you, will do. I reposted on the google-chrome-developer-tools as well, before I saw your latest comment, but will work on getting the test case together.

Comment: @RobW I've reported here: crbug.com/362781

Comment: @RobW thanks again for investigating, a quite sloppy mistake on my part and one I hadn't really considered since executeScript was falling back to the current tab (and thus expected behavior when docked). If you want to write up your response to the test case as an answer here I'll mark it correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The test case of [your bug report](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=362781) contains a typo.

he `onMessage` event listener in your event page expects the tab ID to be available as `message.tabId`:

```
chrome.tabs.executeScript(message.tabId,{ file: 'insert.js', runAt: 'document_idle' });
```

However, in the devtools page, the message is being sent as "tabID" (note: capital D).

```
chrome.runtime.sendMessage({type: 'newpageload',tabID:  chrome.devtools.inspectedWindow.tabId});
```

Because `message.tabId` is undefined in the event page, Chrome defaults to inserting the content script in the active tab of the [current window](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/windows#current-window). When the developer tools is undocked, this tab is (coincidentally) identical to the inspected tab, so you did not notice the error.

When the devtools are undocked, the current window is the devtools. Since you cannot script the developer tools, nothing appears to happen. If you read the value of [`chrome.runtime.lastError`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime#property-lastError) in the callback of [`chrome.tabs.executeScript`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-executeScript), you would have noticed that you're trying to insert the script in the wrong window.

After changing the "tabId" to "tabID", the test case works as expected.